# Migrating from Squarespace

Tags: drupal, migration, content-management-system, wagtail, squarespace

We have a Squarespace site (nataal.com) that has been steadily growing over the past 4 years. It now has in the region of 670 pages and is getting quite unwieldy, particularly when trying to scroll through the various page and link menus. Squarespace says 1000 max according to  documentation, but < 400 recommended. Creating a user index for the pages is also a problem, ours now runs to about 50 pages in its own right (12 entries per page including thumbnails and captions). That's the way the creative people want it and who am I to argue!

Has anybody had experience, good or bad, of migrating such a site to a better platform? I have some exposure to Drupal and I think it would have worked well had it been used from the start. I have also heard good things about Wagtail, but I've never seen it in operation. Or is there some other platform I should consider?

So, what I'm looking for is a CMS platform that can

Easily handle more pages than Squarespace

Migrate from Squarespace keeping most if not all the structure of each page.

Automate the construction of page indexes.

Fairly east to tweak the layout of any given page to suite the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Both Wagtail CMS and Drupal can support thousands of pages quite easily. In my opinion, Wagtail is MUCH easier to work with than Drupal - and a lot of websites that end up migrating to Wagtail have historically been from WordPress and Drupal (not all, but *many!*).

I can only give you info on ways to help guide your decision because ultimately the CMS you pick is your decision.

Drupal is a PHP based CMS that typically uses Apache and MySQL. A few pros to using this is the popularity in the tech stack and easy deployment. But the down side is the code gets messy, unruly, and eventually very difficult to maintain due to the structure of PHP as a language (not in all cases, but in *most* cases this ends up happening).

Wagtail is a Python based CMS that sits on top of a different database called Postgres but it can be swapped out for just about any other database you prefer (Postgres is well known as the "enterprise version" of open source databases). Wagtail also sits on a massively popular framework called Django which has SO MANY great features (too many to list here), but amongst those great features is *security*. With a Django/Wagtail site you'll have to do more developer work. There isn't really a "plugin" system like in WordPress, but that also means extending the longevity if your codebase and it's easier to maintain your code as it grows (due to the nature of Python, Django and then Wagtail).

I think the biggest downside to migrating such a large site is going to be moving all of your content over. In Wagtail you can structure all your page slugs to be the exact same as your squarespace site which is nice. But there's not an "easy" solution to migrating that much data from Squarespace to another CMS. (But please *do* make the migration, even if it's painful to do because it'll only get more painful as time goes on and your site gets bigger).

Regardless of which CMS you end up choosing, any dynamic website can create index pages for you very quickly and easily.

With all that said, should you choose to take the Wagtail route, I have a full series that can take you from "zero to hero" on YouTube at [wagtail.io/course](https://wagtail.io/course). We also have a great community where you can get support on the [Wagtail Slack](http://wagtail.io/slack) as well.

Good luck with the migration!

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail can certainly support those requirements.

If you're in Oxfordshire, UK, you should come and see Torchbox (the creators of Wagtail) to talk about it!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change your Squarespace account to developer, the downside is that you can't get back to the normal one, but you can change it to developer mode and work it with Angular. I made this [www.rudagt.squarespace.com](http://www.rudagt.squarespace.com) and I  will do this, cause the huge amounto of content, but, I have clients so for them SQspace is better interfaz than much others.
Good luck!